# How to declare two different application in Android Manifest or merge them into one application class

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-manifest, android-volley

I have merged two packages into one: [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) and [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/) into one. The problem that I'm facing is that I can only declare one Application in android manifest. I have two applications to declare: AppController for Volley and ParseApplication for Parse package.

What should I do to declare only one application in Android Manifest?
I'm still a newbie and trying to learn by merging some code that I find online for practice what I read or watch online.

Thank you !

Update: 
Here is the Appcontroller class:

```
Public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
LruBitmapCache mLruBitmapCache;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        getLruBitmapCache();
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mLruBitmapCache);
    }

    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public LruBitmapCache getLruBitmapCache() {
    if (mLruBitmapCache == null)
        mLruBitmapCache = new LruBitmapCache();
    return this.mLruBitmapCache;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    // Add your initialization code here
  Parse.initialize(this, "ui3OHYCLF4wlTNZcbkPhRkiEN4yiURuRZxYnXMSX", "J60b54ajmUuDk7wu94GmX3DpBbJOrv5IzSuRd5V2");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this
    // line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.listviewfeed"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
          IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
          to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
        -->

    <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.listviewfeed.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.listviewfeed.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="info.androidhive.listviewfeed.ParseApplication"

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Feed_Activity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".Welcome"></activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

`
Debug

> 10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime: Process: info.androidhive.listviewfeed, PID: 1688
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.listviewfeed/info.androidhive.listviewfeed.Feed_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.RequestQueue info.androidhive.listviewfeed.app.AppController.getRequestQueue()' on a null object reference
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.volley.RequestQueue info.androidhive.listviewfeed.app.AppController.getRequestQueue()' on a null object reference
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at info.androidhive.listviewfeed.Feed_Activity.onCreate(Feed_Activity.java:57)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>   10-31 11:00:03.570 1688-1688/info.androidhive.listviewfeed E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: "What should I do to declare only one application in Android Manifest?" -- have only one concrete subclass of `Application`. No library should require a magic `Application` class, just for this sort of problem. I cannot speak about Parse and whether their `ParseApplication` is some required item or not. However, Volley does not seem to have `AppController`, AFAICT. If that is your class, have it extend `ParseApplication` instead of `Application`.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me. The `AppController` is responsible for returning cache if my understanding is correct. This class is used in another class `Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();` used then to  `Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);` I still get a NullPointerException in the `Cache cache = ...`
`

Comment: "I still get a NullPointerException" -- then you need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, this would include the Java stack trace for your crash, plus the classes from your code that are referenced in that stack trace. We cannot help you debug code that we cannot see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by merging the `ParseApplication` class into `AppController` class and declaring only the `AppController` as `application` into the `manifest`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want one app and just want to use each of the activities and classes from the two merged packages, you can add all `activity` declarations from the `application` tag of the second package to the `application` tag of the `manifest` file of the first package.

Now only use the `manifest` file of the first package, and change the app name and icon to whatever you like.

Hope that helps, otherwise please explain what you want to achieve in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I didn't really understood what you advise me to do. I can only declare one `application` in ` Manifest`.  I've provided more code to be more clear.